# How to convert a "yyyy/mm" field to "yyyy/mm/dd"?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I am trying to edit an existing date field of the form "yyyy/mm" to a format that the TimeManager Plugin for QGIS can handle - I guess "yyyy/mm/dd" will do it.

I've got as far as opening the attribute field table, adding a new table and getting the field calculator up - but I can't see how to simply add a "/01" to the existing info in the field without getting a "invalid expression" error.

Comment: can you screenshot how you are putting the expression in the field calculator so we can see the syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the **Field Calculator**, create a new *String* field and use the name of the date field as the expression:

```
"Date_field"
```

Next, check the *Update existing field* option and select the "Date_field". Then use this expression to copy the values from the string field with the added `/01`:

```
"String_field" + '/01'
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks - that did it - I was stupidly including a '=' before the statement.

Comment: @user3722921 - Awesome buddy, glad you got it working! And not stupid at all, it's always easy to make mistakes :)